# Select within another select syntax in Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, select

I have mysql select command that counts the number of rows return based on two select commands as follows:

```
  SELECT  count(*)-1  as elmlen FROM  invertedindextb WHERE
  dewId IN 
         (SELECT  dewId  FROM  invertedindextb WHERE eTypeId = ? and trm = ?) 
  and docId IN
         (SELECT  docId  FROM  invertedindextb WHERE eTypeId = ? and trm = ?)
```

I wrote a python function that implements the above select command as follows:

```
def lenOfNode (self, cursor,  eTypeId , trm):


    sql = """ SELECT COUNT(*)-1 AS LEN FROM invertedindextb WHERE  \
              dewId IN ("SELECT  dewId  FROM  invertedindextb WHERE eTypeId = '%d' and trm = '%s' %(eTypeId,trm)") \
              and  docId IN  ("SELECT docId FROM  invertedindextb WHERE eTypeId = '%d' and trm = '%s' %(eTypeId,trm)") """

    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    print results[0]
    return results[0]
```

Although the function run ( but computes wrong answer),  I am not sure whether the syntax of the select command is correct in python.

Can somebody help me with correct syntax for the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `\` in the `sql` string, you started it with triple quote thus all new lines are ok already.

You placed your arguments to the `%` operator into the string, turning them into literal text. Try to print your query before executing it, like

```
def lenOfNode (self, cursor,  eTypeId , trm):
    sql = """ SELECT COUNT(*)-1 AS LEN FROM invertedindextb WHERE  \
              dewId IN ("SELECT  dewId  FROM  invertedindextb WHERE eTypeId = '%d' and trm = '%s' %(eTypeId,trm)") \
              and  docId IN  ("SELECT docId FROM  invertedindextb WHERE eTypeId = '%d' and trm = '%s' %(eTypeId,trm)") """

    print "My real sql query was:\n", sql

    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    print results[0]
    return results[0]
```

Your mistace is that `"aaa %d" % (10,)` string (which should give `"aaa 10"`) is turned into `'''"aaa %d" % (10,)'''` (and will give `'"aaa %d" % (10,)'`), which is not what you intended. For me, the best way to develop an eye to such things was to try all suspicious part of my code in IPython console with %ed magick command.

And using `%s` in sql query introduces direct vulnerability - sql injection - in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I change the code as you suggested but i still have problem

Answer (score 0):

I forget to add the "and" operator between the first select command and second in the where clause so on adding the and operator as follows the def runs and return correct result:

```
 sql = """ SELECT (COUNT(*)-1) AS LEN FROM invertedindextb WHERE
             (dewId IN (SELECT  dewId  FROM  invertedindextb WHERE eTypeId = '%d' and trm = '%s') and
              docId IN  (SELECT  docId  FROM  invertedindextb WHERE eTypeId = '%d' and trm = '%s')) """ %(eTypeId,trm,eTypeId,trm)
```